# How do I create an assets folder using current Android Studio (3.5.3)?

Tags: android-studio, android-assets

Does anyone know how to create an assets folder in an Android project? There are lots of answers to this from about 5 years ago, but they do not work with the current version of Android Studio (3.5.3).

Answer (score 16):

Go through File > New > Folder > Assets folder.

No need to check change folder location.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I do not get a Folder option, I just get File->New->Directory, and that does not have an "Assets Folder" menu item.

Comment: @MartinEllison First select the **app folder from left panel** and then click on the File > ... > Folder. You will get Assets Folder there.

Comment: @MartinEllison hope my answer clears your doubt. First you have to select `main` folder then do right click.

Answer (score 2):

The `assets` folder's default location is inside of `app/src/main` folder.

Just move to that **main** directory inside `YourProjectName -> app -> src -> main`

> Right click -> New -> Directory -> Type **assets** -> OK

Thats it.